# Setprecision() for a float number in C++?

Tags: c++, types

In C++, 
What are the random digits that are displayed after giving *setprecision*() for a floating point number?

Note: After setting the fixed flag.

example:

```
float f1=3.14;
cout < < fixed<<setprecision(10)<<f1<<endl;
```

we get random numbers for the remaining 7 digits? But it is not the same case in double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to be aware of:

1. `float`s are stored in binary.
2. `float` has a maximum of 24 significant bits.  This is equivalent to 7.22 significant digits.

So, to your computer, there's no such number as 3.14.  The closest you can get using `float` is 3.1400001049041748046875.

`double` has 53 significant bits (~15.95 significant digits), so you get a more accurate approximation, 3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875.  The "noise" digits don't show up with `setprecision(10)`, but would with `setprecision(17)` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

They're not really "random" -- they're the (best available) decimal representation of that binary fraction (will be exact only for fractions whose denominator is a power of two, e.g., `3.125` *would* display exactly).

Of course that changes depending on the number of bits available to represent the binary fraction that best approaches the decimal one you originally entered as a literal, i.e., single vs double precision floats.

Not really a C++ specific issue (applies to all languages using binary floats, typically to exploit the machine's underlying HW, i.e., most languages).  For a very bare-bone tutorial, I recommend reading [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/).